# Storyboard file won't update visually

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, storyboard

Whenever I change somehting in a .storyboard file it won't update visually.

Examples:

- If I change a constraints constant value it doens't update (and it doesn't turn yellow or red or anything)
- If I delete a view it looks like it's still there although I can't select it anymore
- If I move a UILabel it looks like it didn't move, but I can only select it again in the position I moved it to

If I restart Xcode then the UI is updated. I've tried the latest Xcode version and the 11.5 Beta version too. I've tried rebooting the computer, cleaned build folders, derived data and reinstalling the command line tools.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I realized that only ONE view controller is bugged, all the others update normally.

Comment: Do you have any `IBDesignable` views in your storyboard? I've seen weird stuff like this happen before if you've got `IBDesignable`s that have trouble rendering in your storyboard. It seems to sometimes bug out and cause the storyboard to not update any views visually.

Comment: There's only one view that uses IBDesignable, but it's in another view controller within the same storyboard.
While checking for that I realized that only ONE view controller is bugged, all the others update normally. It is not the view controller with IBDesignable btw

Comment: Okay, well that's weird. Now I'm not really sure what could be causing it. I still think it'd be worth a try to remove the `IBDesignable` temporarily just to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I didn't build this project so I didn't know it, but I just found an IBDesignable in all the view controllers that weren't being updated. When I remove them it instantly works.

These view are from 2 old libs that are used in the project. Do you know any fixes/workarounds? I would love to not have to change libs or reimplement these views

Comment: Ahh, okay, glad you figured it out! Hmm, if the views are in libraries, I'm not too sure of a way to fix or workaround that. Maybe you could create wrapper view classes that wrap the views from the libraries, and then use those wrapper views in the storyboard instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the issue was that my Podfile was missing `use_frameworks!`. Adding that like and running `pod update` fixed the issue!